# To find diameter of moon

Tags: trigonometry

The moon's distance from earth is $360000$ kms and its diameter subtends an angle of $31'$ at eye of observer.i have to To find diameter of moon.

how do i start?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Draw a picture.  The moon occupies a small part of the arc of a circle.  You are given the radius and the subtended angle.  What fraction of the whole circle is $31'?$  What is the circumference of the circle?